# Change the font attribute of TextView relatively

Tags: android

In Java Swing, I can change the attributes of `Font` relatively, without having to know its actual attributes. For example, I can say, I want to make this label's font 1 pixel less than its current size, without having to know what is current size.

```
private void initComponents() {
    jLabel12.setFont(jLabel12.getFont().deriveFont(
        jLabel12.getFont().getSize()-1f));
}
```

In Android, how I can achieve the similar stuff for `TextView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    TextView txtview=new TextView(this);
    float fontSize = txtview.getTextSize();
    txtview.setTextSize(fontSize-1.0f);
    txtview.setText("this is test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the same method :

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
float currentSize = text.getTextSize();
text.setTextSize(currentSize-1.0f);
```